# Coordinate chart of full rank is an "open mapping"

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

In our Riemannian geometry class we were asked to verify the following:

Let $M$ be a $k$-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\varphi:U\subset\mathbb{R}^k\to M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ coordinate chart with $U$ open. Then if $\varphi'(x)$ has full rank $\forall x\in U$ we have $\varphi(U)$ is open in $M$  (which I'm assuming means $\varphi(U)=M\cap V$ for some $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$
, $V$ open?)

Any points of advice to get me started in the right direction? I not sure how I should approach proving something is open in the subset-topology sense.

Comment: Take a look at the [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all you need to do know is [inverse mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \supset U \times \mathbb{R}^{n-k} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the extension of $\varphi$ given by
$$
f(x) = f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (\varphi_1(x),\dots,\varphi_k(x),x_{k+1},\dots,x_n),
$$
where $\varphi = (\varphi_i)$. By the assumption the square matrix $(D_j\varphi_i(x))_{i,j}$ has full rank (for appropriate choice of $j$'s).

Now you only need to show that the Jacobi matrix of $f$ is invertible, which is easy (or obvious).

**Edit:** While writing this I didn't see Bill's comment which of course gives the same idea, but maybe this answer would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me enough to finish the proof.